# O modo verbal subjuntivo não é mais utilizado em Portugal?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

No dia de hoje há o seguinte trecho de artigo no site da CNN Portugal:

"A ministra espanhola do Trabalho, Yolanda Díaz, propôs uma solução para combater a desigualdade social e que consiste numa “herança” automática de 20.000 euros a conceder a todos os jovens a partir dos 18 anos para garantir **que têm** "um futuro, independentemente do seu sobrenome."

Se eu escrevesse assim em uma redação escolar no Brasil, teria sido certamente repreendido pelo professor, pois aprendemos que em casos como o citado devemos sempre empregar o verbo em seu modo modo subjuntivo, pois:

"O modo subjuntivo é usado para transmitir um **acontecimento irreal, hipotético ou desejado, ou seja, de possível realização, mas ainda incerto**. 
Através dos tempos verbais do modo subjuntivo, expressam-se **ações imprecisas, que ainda não foram realizadas e que dependem de outras para acontecer**.
O modo subjuntivo é um dos modos verbais, juntamente com o modo indicativo e o modo imperativo. Os modos verbais indicam a posição do emissor ou agente face a ação verbal."

Assim, no português do Brasil, ficaria:

"A ministra espanhola do Trabalho, Yolanda Díaz, propôs uma solução para combater a desigualdade social e que consiste numa “herança” automática de 20.000 euros a conceder a todos os jovens a partir dos 18 anos para garantir **que tenham** "um futuro, independentemente do seu sobrenome."

Em Portugal, então, parece haver uma preferência por se evitar o verbo no modo subjuntivo, fugindo-se, assim, da norma culta.

No Brasil vemos pessoas com baixa escolaridade falarem/escreverem dessa mesma forma, evitando o subjuntivo, mas jamais em sites de jornais, revistas ou canais de TV. Exemplo:
"Vou aos EUA, mesmo que eu tenho que aprender inglês para me virar por lá."

Comment: Por favor. Que eu saiba, essa pergunta não mostra nenhuma pesquisa. A frase é um tradução. Pegar uma frase solta para construir esse argumento me parece um exagero.

Comment: @Lambie, onde você viu ser uma tradução? Eu chequei o *site* e não consegui achar uma indicação.

Comment: @Lambie Desculpe-me. Não sei ao certo se compreendi o que quis dizer. A jornalista portuguesa Beatriz Céu, da CNN Portugal, teria feito uma tradução? Você a conhece? https://cnnportugal.iol.pt/yolanda-diaz/espanha/ministra-espanhola-propoe-heranca-universal-de-20-000-para-todos-os-jovens-a-partir-dos-18-anos/20230706/64a67a1ad34e72171a0ae416

Comment: Não, João. Acredito que uma ministra espanhola teria falado em espanhol e que o site traduziu o trecho. Em todo caso, se houve um erro de tempo de verbo, isso não leva a pensar que os portugueses não usam o subjuntivo. Que ideia. :) Esse error poderia se fazer em qualquer português.

Comment: @Lambie Então, como português, julga que há mesmo um erro naquele parágrafo? Me causa surpresa dizer isso, pois pensei que aos olhos dos portugueses não havia qualquer erro, até por se tratar de um artigo que antes da publicação passou pelo revisor e também pelo editor. Obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: Não se pode saber o que pensam os "portugueses". O internet está cheio de erros e coisas estrañhas; esse seria mais um. :)